# Need to strip a leading character (# or +) from this string

Tags: javascript

In the cases below I need to strip either the first "#"  or "+" character for vars b & c so they can become vars a & a1 which are used to be a string in a new url that's built elsewhere.

Here is the code:

```
var b = "http://www.somewhere.com/search/#foo+bar+baz"

var c = "http://www.somewhere.com/search/++bar+baz"

var a = b.split("/")[4].split("+").slice(0, 1);
var a1 = c.split("/")[4].split("+").slice(0, 1);
```

[Here is the fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/rowbuck/7FV4Z/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me on your fiddle.

```
var b = "http://www.somewhere.com/search/#foo+bar+baz"

var c = "http://www.somewhere.com/search/++bar+baz"

var a = b.split("/")[4].split("+").slice(0, 1);
if(a[0].indexOf('#') != -1){a = a[0].split('#')[1]}
var a1 = c.split("/")[4].split("+");
var i=0;
while(true){
    if(a1[i] != ''){a1 = a1[i]; break;}
    i++;
}
$("#result").html(a);
$("#result2").html(a1);

console.log(a);
console.log(a1);
```

Comment: Thanks! That works for me too. Haven't studied what you've done there yet but the result looks proper.

Comment: My example shows two cases using two vars but in practice there's only var b which could have either `#foo+bar+baz` or `++bar+baz` following the `search/` bit. So, how can I consolidate since `a1` is there for the example not in practice. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Do you know whether the + or # would come first, or could it be either?

Comment: Ouch. Just noticed that the `#` is actually `%23` in practice

Comment: Yep, that worked. Multiple occurrences of those characters preceding may be an issue

Comment: Thanks again—I'm all set now.

Answer (score 0):

Updated [your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7FV4Z/1/)

You can replace the first occurrence of a char with using a regex quite easily:

```
var a = b.replace(/[#+]/,'');
var a1 = c.replace(/[#+]/,'');
```

Without the `g` modifier it will only replace the first one it finds.

Comment: Or if you need to avoid changing occurrences prior to the last slash, `var a = b.substring(0, b.lastIndexOf('/')) + '/' + b.substring(b.lastIndexOf('/') + 1).replace(/[#+]/,'');`

Comment: @mark Thanks. I tried the replace earlier and it threw an error because it's an object.  Should have noted that in the question. Your example seems to skip a step I need.

Comment: @mark I think I understand yours better now. I need to strip the character(s) first then get the slice? [Like this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rowbuck/7FV4Z/17/)?

Comment: @mark Ouch. Just noticed that the `#` is actually `%23` in practice.

Comment: @user1452893: That depends. I'm still not quite sure what output you want. Is it "foo+bar+baz" and "+bar+baz" or what? Splitting it on slashes and taking the 4th chunk seems flaky. Do you want the last segment? Does the last segment always start with exactly 1 unwanted char? Where is that char coming from?

Comment: @mark Thanks for the note. I didn't grasp the problem as well as I thought after testing more scenarios. I'm trying to get the first string after `search/` and only the first one before any other `+` character occurs. The `+` character is used to separate multiple strings. I only can use and need the first one. The `#` character may precede the string I need too. Again, only the first string is desired. To further complicate, if there are any combinations of or series of either of those characters I need them stripped. For example. if `+++#foo+bar++baz` is there I want only `foo`.

Comment: tl:dr version: I need to get `foo` from the string following `search/` if it is `++++#foo+bar+baz++#yikes `